# JS live preview of HTML forms based on keypress: Only update from active field, or all the fields all the time?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form with ~10 fields used to update a website. Using keypress/keyup events on each of these, I update a live preview of the resulting website, basically using

```
previewEl.innerHTML = (formEl.value ? formEl.value : 'default message');
```

where `'default message'` is shown when the form field is empty.

My questions, based on lack of knowledge of javascript performance under a variety of browsers/machines, are:

1. Should I have one update function for each form element which updates the corresponding live preview element, or is it OK performance-wise to have a single update function which updates all live preview elements based on all fields for every single change in any field?
2. Will the answer be affected by running `formEl.value` through some simple function which does a few regex search/replace operations? (None of the fields contain much text.)

Edit: Here's a minimal working example using a single form element:

```js
<form>
    <input type="text" id="formEl1" onkeypress="update1();" onkeyup="update1();" />
</form>
<p id="previewEl1"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update1() {
        document.getElementById('previewEl1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('formEl1').value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? It is hard to make assumptions without a clear picture of what you are doing. But yes, `innerHTML` will likely destroy the running values.

Comment: Minimal working example added. What do you mean by "destroy the running values"?

Comment: I thought you were outputting your input tags with innerHtml. This should be ok.